how to start the text by completing the table fully?

Like I know there might be commands, \clearpage and \newpage did not work

\lipsum[1]
\scriptsize{

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.20cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{3cm}|p{8cm}|}

\caption{Summary of VEP-based BCI Studies} \\

\hline

\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Modality} & \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Data Set} & \textbf{Model}  & \textbf{Performance \& Challenges} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Modality} & \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Data Set} & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Performance \& Challenges} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

\cite{piotr_bialas_2014}& SSVEP & Tested consumer-grade equipment detecting SSVEP responses with high-frequency stimuli. & Private dataset: 15 participants (including 3 females), 40 trials/session. & \textbf{Feature Extraction:} Common Spatial Filtering for signal dimension reduction; Canonical Correlation. \newline \textbf{Classification:} 3 logistic regression classifiers.  & Low Frequencies (17Hz-25Hz) - $80\%\pm15\%$; \newline Higher Frequencies (31Hz-40Hz) - $67\%\pm12\%$; \newline Frequencies 35Hz–40Hz - $64\%\pm22\%$. \newline \textbf{Challenges:} 1. Brain responses for higher frequencies are smaller, making detection harder. \newline 2. System performance varies across users. \newline 3. Balance needed between reduced fatigue and technical difficulty in detecting high-frequency SSVEPs. \\
\hline
\hline 

\end{longtable}
}
\newpage
\small
\lipsum
\clearpage


Your question is very unclear and you have not provided code in a form that people can run to see the problem. You are forcing the column widths with p{.. so your table does not fit in a column, also longtable explicitly does not work in two column, perhaps you want to use \onecolumn before the table and \twocolumn after it,

yes thanks worked
but what about this empty space after the table before the two column text starts? is it okay for IEEE access or for the journal papers?

It is your document you can choose to add the table  at a place that has a good page break

I mean how two columns can fill the gap after the table? which command?

standard two column can not do that it can only switch at a page break,

If your image is a reflection of your real document why are you using longtable ??? that is for multi-page tables but your table just seems like a few lines.

off-topic: \scriptsize does not take an argument. it switches all subsequent text to script size, unless and until the current group ends or an explicit change to the size is requested again.
